# How do I determine the authentication method of an iFrame parent in ASP .Net?

Tags: authentication, iframe, parent

I have a website which hosts some sub virtual directory content within an iFrame. I have setup shared forms based authentication between the parent site and the virtual directory such that when either expires the user is redirected back to a specific login page on the parent site.

This works great, however, I need to be able to determine from within the iFrame whether the parent site is using NT or Forms based authentication. In the event that the parent site is using NT authentication I wish to prevent a javascript redirect happening from within the iFrame and simply leave a mesage on the page to be displayed wihtin the iFrame area.